# Using C#, how do I lock a mouse inside a window for gaming purposes

Tags: c#

I wanted to add this feature to my program but I don't know what to google or the functions needed to do this. Its for Wacraft3 on window mode. I want the mouse to get locked inside the window when the window is active. thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, that would be grounds (for me at least) for an instant uninstall of your program (my desktop belongs to me, not to some program). Others may have a different view, of course.

Comment: No, this program is just for me. and its for the game I'm playing if ever I give this out. I will surely add an option for them to enable or disable this feature.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Cursor.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip.aspx):

```
Cursor.Clip = yourForm.RectangleToScreen(yourForm.ClientRectangle);
```